# Windows batch command to delete folders only

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder, which has files and folders inside it like

```
 C:/MyFolder
 C:/MyFolder/File1.txt
 C:/MyFolder/File2.txt
 C:/MyFolder/File3.sql
 C:/MyFolder/Folder1
 C:/MyFolder/Folder1/File5.txt
```

What batch command do I need to use to delete all the folders and contents inside them without deleting files inside my folder. Example : Delete Folder1,Folder1/File5.txt but retain File1.txt,File2.txt and File3.sql?

Comment: Use `del` (or `erase`) to delete files and `rmdir` (or `rd`) to delete empty directories; type the command followed by `/?` in a command prompt window for help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows you the commands - if you are happy with them then remove the `echo` keyword and run it again.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\MyFolder\*") do echo rd "%%a" /q /s
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the coomand, but when I tried something like this "for /d %%a in (".") do rd "%%a" /q /s" (as I need to delete from current directory), it deleted everything not just folders and contents inside them, even the files in current directory got deleted.

Comment: @springbatcher That's not the command I included.  Test the script I used and then let me know if it fails.

Comment: This command did the trick - for /d %%a in ("*") do rd "%%a" /q /s . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

from command prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\someDir"') do @rd /s /q "%~fa"
```

from batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\someDir"') do @rd /s /q "%%~fa"
```

Comment: It needs a path somehow npocmaka, or it could cause mayhem if run in any place.

Answer (score 1):

For DOS/Command prompt use

for /d **%F** in ("path*") do **rmdir** /s /q "**%F**"

Use double % if you use it in a batch file.

for /d **%%F** in ("H:\EDGE-backup*") do **rmdir** /s /q "**%%F**"

I used this to backup the EDGE bookmarks and such, and since XCOPY always brings with it it's root directory subfolders i had to delete these after the copy.

The above worked for this. Result,only files remained in H:\EDGE-backup.